# Why Crystal Report log on prompt

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Why I am still getting user and password prompt on second page in below procedure when executing crystal reports in VS2010 asp.net.
There is no prompt on first page when I click next in viewer it then ask for user id and password.

```
public void connectCrystal(ReportDocument repdoc)
{
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("") + "\\Crystal_Reports\\ABC.rpt");

    ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    conInfo.ServerName = "S1";
    conInfo.DatabaseName = "CR";
    conInfo.UserID = "USER1";
    conInfo.Password = "1234";

    Tables tables = rptDoc.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
    }
    crv.ReportSource = rptDoc;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to set also the table location.

Comment: I cannot check the exact syntax but table object has a property location. Location may contain the full name of the table so it will look like DatabaseName.dbo.TableName. If you are changing the database you need to prepare the new location and use table.Location = "your new location here" to set it

Comment: We can set the database and table locations in design mode of reports which I did. I applied my same code in desktop application it works perfectly but in Web version it always pop up user log on when I click next page from crystal report browser there is no log on prompt on first page.

Comment: Ah, OK. I missed that. Web application will loose the instantiated report object and will try to instantiate it again. You need to save ReportDocument rptDoc to a session variable and load it on page load.